# Carrier Ethernet - Implementation detail at the UNI needed

Tags: ethernet

Metro Ethernet Forum (MEF) standard number 4 identifies two items of equipment - the UNI-C and UNI-N (UNI Client and UNI Network respectively) - on either side of the UNI. In so far as general terms go, this is simple to follow. Please see the diagram below (from MEF 4).

[image]

Carrier Ethernet Certified Professional (CECP) courseware takes a step further and refers to a "network interface device" (NID) and equates the NID to a UNI-N. Please see the diagram below.

[image]

What doesn't emerge clearly is the detail about the physical location of the NID. Is it (at least typically, if such a typical implementation exists) in the operator's access network's footprint? Is it in the customer's premises?

Comment: A NID is usually hanging on the customers wall, 'tho it can be in a central telco closet. Every NID I've ever had was in my space. (every NID I've ever installed was in the customer space, but there isn't always a physical box.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What doesn't emerge clearly is the detail about the physical location
> of the NID. Is it (at least typically, if such a typical
> implementation exists) in the operator's access network's footprint?
> Is it in the customer's premises?

The physical location of the NID will vary. At some sites, it can be located in the customer premises, just like the telco equipment for voice/data can be in the customer premises, and, at other sites, it may be more remote, just like the telco equipment for voice/data can be in a more remote location.

There is no one-size-fits-all answer to your question.

Comment: Thank you. Can you point to a reference that shows such implementation detail? It seems hard to come by.

Comment: Unfortunately, resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic here. I can say that mostly in big buildings, we see the equipment somewhere in the building, often in the building utility room, and sometimes in our own space in the building. I have seen it where one building of a cluster (whether or not the buildings are commonly owned) has the telecommunications equipment for all the buildings. Sometimes you may see it in a box or shed in the parking lot or grounds of the site. The determination is where the carrier claims its ownership of the cables ends, and yours begins.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that ! Thank you for  the tips.